# Do Yersinia genus spp have anything movement factors?

Tags: microbiology

It can spread in blood (Type III secretion system -> apoptosis).
I am interested if there is any others ways to move.

**Do Yersinia spp have anything virulence factors to move?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yersinia enterocolitica does express flagella at a temperature around 25°C, but not at 37°C. [Kapatral et al.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/8830263)
Besides that it can rely on peristaltic movement in the intestines.

Yersinia pestis is as far as I know nonmotile in the host, but motile if isolated [Medical Microbiology](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK7798/).

As there are some other Yersinia species, including Y. pseudotuberculosis of course, I think you cannot totally generalize the answer for Yersinia spp., but searching for the Yersinia of interest with "flagella", "motility", "movement" or similar keywords on Pubmed might help.